# Linq To SQL vs Entity Framework Connection Strings

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, configuration, connection-string

Thanks for taking a look at my post.

I've been working with linq to sql and have generally been happy, until i just noticed that database table names are hardcoded into the classes/dbml files-- which can't work in our environment. We need to be able to have database names completely changeable via web.config-- in one place. That's a definite requirement.

Do you know how this can be achieved with Linq To Sql? If not, does the Entity Framework behave in the same manner? Perhaps i will have to port my model.

Appreciated!

In other words, i need "Tourism_DB" in the DataContext file:

```
[System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="Tourism_DB")]
    public partial class TourismDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
    {
```

as well as this text in the dbml

```
<Database Name="Tourism_DB" Class="TourismDataContext" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/linqtosql/dbml/2007">
```

to NOT be used, and the value in the web.config to be used anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method i found here worked the best http://msmvps.com/blogs/superska/archive/2009/03/13/linq-to-sql-connectionstring-in-web-config.aspx. It laid out the full process.

Answer (score 1):

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2008/05/20/connection-strings-in-linq-to-sql-classes.aspx

Answer (score 1):

note you can do this with LINQ to SQL:

```
Dim c As New MyClassesDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString1").ToString())
```